# Want to add a New column in MS Access query via SQL

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables they all have the same column header Name, Number I have joined them using the union command as shown below:

```
SELECT Name, Number
FROM table1
Union all
select name, number
from table2
UNION ALL select name, number
from table3;
```

Every thing is right up till here. Now I want to add a new column which should contain the information about from which table this data have been taken. I am using the alter table command but it gives error.

Kindly help me. I am working on MS access 2007.

Comment: post your command and the error....

Comment: For future reference: When you say "I am using the alter table command", you need to post what you're actually trying ("the alter table command" isn't enough), and when you say "gives error" you need to tell us what error (including the **exact error messsage**). You have that information right in front of you, and there is no excuse for not providing it in your question. We can't see your screen or read your mind. If you want help, give us the information we can use to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` only works on actual tables, not query results.

You simply need to add the information as a pseudo-column to your current query:

```
SELECT 
  Name, Number, 'Table1' as TableName
FROM 
  table1
Union all
select 
  name, number, 'Table2'
from 
  table2
UNION ALL 
select 
  name, number, 'Table3'
from table3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in as a column in each subquery:

```
SELECT Name, Number, 'table1' as which
FROM table1
Union all
select name, number, 'table2' as which
from table2
UNION ALL
select name, number, 'table3' as which
from table3;
```